# VS 2017: Double click in on changed file opens it instead of diff tool?

Tags: visual-studio, beyondcompare

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (latest version 15.5.3) and Beyond Compare as a diff tool and git as version control. Usually, when I double click on a changed file in the 'Changes' window, Beyond Compare opens and the diffs are shown. A couple of days ago the behavior changed. Now a double click opens the file itself in the editor instead of opening my diff tool.

When I want to view the diffs, I have to select 'Compare with unmodified...' from the context menu. So the diff tool itself still works fine. Only the behavior of the double click changed, which is quite annoying.

I searched the settings for a configuration, but didn't find anything.
Did anyone experience the same behavior?
How can I change it back?

Kind regards,
Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange no one else had this problem yet...

Finally, I downloaded the VS installer and executed repair option. After it finished, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Click on **...** in **Git Changes** tab to the right of "Changes" word and choose **"Compare File as Default Action"**.

[image]